# How to perform multiple 2D transformations?

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I want to allow multiple transformations (Rotate, translate, etc...) all at once for a `div` element.

I can't seem to do this, as only one transformation is applied (The first one), using the following code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <style> 
        div {
            width:100px;
            height:75px;
            background-color:#FFCC00;
            border:1px solid black;
        }

        div#div2 {
            transform:rotate(45deg);
            -ms-transform:rotate(45deg); /* IE 9 */
            -moz-transform:rotate(45deg); /* Firefox */      
            -webkit-transform:translate(50px,100px); /* Safari and Chrome */
            -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
            -o-transform:rotate(45deg); /* Opera */
        }

    </style>
    </head>
<body>
    <div>This is a DIV element.</div>
    <div id="div2">This is a DIV element + Transformation</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Tested on Chrome, only the rotation is affected, and the translation has no effect even if it's located first (before the rotation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attributes are unique and don't work like sequential calls to functions, they just override a preceding definition.
So you need to do the transform in one shot, like this (tested in Firefox 17):

```
transform:rotate(45deg) translate(50px,100px);
```

Answer (score 2):

The formal grammar for [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/transform) is:

```
transform: <transform-function> [<transform-function>]* | none
```

In order to execute several transforms, you'd have to concatenate the transform functions:

```css
-webkit-transform: translate(50px,100px) rotate(45deg);
-moz-transform: translate(50px,100px) rotate(45deg);
-ms-transform: translate(50px,100px) rotate(45deg);
-o-transform: translate(50px,100px) rotate(45deg);
transform: translate(50px,100px) rotate(45deg);
```

Here's a **[live demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WZgaz/4/)**, based on your code.

#### Further reading

- [Using CSS Transforms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Tutorials/Using_CSS_transforms) on Mozilla Developer Network